# Getting Data from another URL in C# or AngularJS

Tags: c#, .net, rest, web-scraping

I need data from another Hadoop API URL. But I only get the HTML source code without the data. I am using the following code.

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    String downloadedString = client.DownloadString("http:........");
}
```

**Actual Result:**

```
<tr><th> Configured Capacity:</th><td> *{Total|fmt_bytes}* </td></tr>
```

**Expectation**

```
<tr><th> Configured Capacity:</th><td> 55 </td></tr>
```

I need **55** in my c# code.

Is my expectation possible? If so, please guide me.

Comment: Watch this video, it'll give you some ideas: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vsmxMLmroyQ

Comment: Not entirely sure what this has to do with Hadoop

Comment: @Yan-Sure,Will watch this video

Comment: @cricket_007-Actulay I am installing haddop in my linux server.this providing one url for watching haddop health check.I need particular values from this URL and  show in UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are seeing is that your C# client does not run Javascript, which is what is loading that value from the Hadoop webserver into the placeholder of `{Total|fmt_bytes}`

Also showable with cURL

```sh
$ curl -s http://hadoop-nn1:50070/dfshealth.html#tab-overview | grep Configured
  <tr><th> Configured Capacity:</th><td>{Total|fmt_bytes}</td></tr>
      <th>Configured Capacity</th>
```

So this is not a Hadoop problem. It's your `WebClient`... You need to use something like Selenum WebDriver or PhantomJS instead.

Comment: @cricket_007-I am try to selenim web driver and it throws error"OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'A exception with a null response was thrown sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:58361/session/5fd0b01b7cd0fe09ea9fa6d5a4d3c7b1/element. The status of the exception was UnknownError, and the message was: An error occurred while sending the request. A connection with the server could not be established'"

Comment: You run Curl on Linux machine. The dollar sign is a prompt... Like `C:\>` in windows. Anyways, I've never actually used Selenium, but it seems to say that your response came back empty